# Pathfinding Algorithm not working correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, a-star

For a project at university I would like to program a pathfinder that's using a-star to find the best possible way from end to goal. 
For almost straight lines, the algorithm works fine. When creating obstacles and the path has to turn, the algorithm runs into problems and the program will not be able to find the path. 
I want to try and make the scenario work which is displayed on the left, but so far I didn't find a satisfying solution.

For the algorithm and the GUI you can also go to https://github.com/NiklasB1337/PathFinder1.1

Left side shows where the problem occurs:
https://i.gyazo.com/4488e22ad5610c81061e682514524ed2.png

```
# Astar
def astar(self, maze, start, end):

    """Returns a list of tuples as a path from the given start to the given end in the given maze"""

    # Create start and end node
    start_node = Node(None, start)
    start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
    end_node = Node(None, end)
    end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

    # Initialize open and closed list
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []

    # Add the start node
    open_list.append(start_node)

    # Loop until the end is found
    while len(open_list) > 0:

        # get the current node
        current_node = open_list[0]
        current_index = 0
        for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
            if item.f < current_node.f:
                current_node = item
                current_index = index

        # pop current off open list, add to closed list
        open_list.pop(current_index)
        closed_list.append(current_node)

        # finding the goal
        if current_node == end_node:
            path = []
            current = current_node
            while current is not None:
                path.append(current.position)
                current = current.parent
            return path[::-1]  # Return reversed path

        # generate children
        children = []
        for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0)]:  # Adjacent squares

            # get node position
            node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])

            # make sure the node is within range
            if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (
                    len(maze[len(maze) - 1]) - 1) or node_position[1] < 0:
                continue

            # make sure the terrain is walkable
            if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
                continue

            # create new node
            new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)

            # Append
            children.append(new_node)

        # loop through children
        for child in children:

            # child is on the closed list
            for closed_child in closed_list:
                if child == closed_child:
                    continue

            #cCreate the f, g, and h values
            child.g = current_node.g + 1
            child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + (
                        (child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)
            child.f = child.g + child.h

            # child is already in the open list
            for open_node in open_list:
                if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                    continue

            # add the child to the open list
            open_list.append(child)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking only at the image it appears the start or finish is on an obstacle and isn't reachable. If it's the start block in the top left corner then the first scan for neighbours won't return any. ?